# Исполнение javascript в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать, чтобы `javascript` исполнялся только с определенного разрешения экрана?

***Код:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое *определенного разрешения*?

Comment: Есть определенный скрипт, он работает на ресурсе все время, но мне надо чтобы он не работал на больших разрешениях, а например с разрешения 991px и ниже начинал работать

Comment: Попробуйте `if(window.screen.availWidth < 991){//ваш скрипт}`

Comment: не работает [ссылка] http://prntscr.com/oayn51

Comment: @АлександрЮзвяк пожалуйста, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Можно повесить обработчик на resize и проверять разрешения.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1200) {
      // some code
    }
    else {
      // code that not fired when < 1200
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pe9oj6b2/1/ ссылка на fiddle. Нужно проверять первую загрузку и ресайз после работы.

Comment: [ссылка] https://codepen.io/alexgood2015/pen/xoawWa
а вот это скрин у меня [ссылка] http://prntscr.com/oaz0et
на разрешении больше 991 все под каталогом должно отображаться, а на <991 скрываться, и только при клике на каталог открываться/закрываться - я говорю именно про разрешение экрана, а не про расширение